# Visual Studio 10.0 cannot insert values into a table with an identity field (syntax error)

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

My issue is that I have created a table for a local db in Visual Studio 10.0 using C# and I want to have an auto-incrementing field which I have setup.  The table is created and the identity field seems to be setup correctly and everything seems fine, but I always get a syntax error on the insert when I use an identity field -- so I imagine I have a stupid little typo, but perhaps this is just not supported using VS?

This is the create table string and execution:

```
-connection string omitted-
string createTableString = @"CREATE TABLE [Test](
[Test_ID] [int] IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[OtherField] [varchar] (50))";
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(createTableString, con); 
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And this is what I'm using to insert into the table:

```
string insertString = @"INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('sometext')";
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(insertString, con);
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that I've tried this as well and get the same syntax error:

```
string insertString = @"INSERT INTO Test (OtherField) VALUES ('sometext')";
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(insertString, con);
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also note that for this project I must do this via these scripting commands in Visual Studio.  Is this possible?  Thanks very much ahead of time.

Comment: What exactly is the syntax error? Are you able to edit the table in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: what is the error/exception message when you command run, also after  your table created, can you add 1 from sql?

Comment: Yes, I am able to edit the table in SQL Management studio.  In the show data mode, I can tab right through the first column, enter a value in the second column, and it will populate the first column with the auto-incremented correct number.  So the table itself seems to be working and setup correctly, but the insert command is somehow not addressing the identity field (for the increment).  The error is 'incorrect syntax near Test' (referring to the second instance, the error is on the line command1.ExecuteNonQuery()) 'SqlException was unhandled by user code'

Comment: did you try to run `INSERT INTO Test (OtherField) VALUES ('sometext')` on management studio query window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts look correct, I can only assume it has to do with the owner of the table. SQL makes the current user the owner of the table. Try [youruser].[Test] and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, no dice.  Adding user or not adding user notwithstanding, it works fine if I lose the identity field stuff, but it doesn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Possible test is the SQL keyword, try to add brackets around it: `[test]`.